# Activation of Multiple Webcams Simultaneously for Video Recording (Logitech C270)

Tags: python, camera, opencv

I needed two cameras for a project requirement. To test the working of the tow cameras together I wrote a short that goes as follows:

{

```
   import cv2,os
   import numpy as np

   webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   webcam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

   while True:
   ret0,frame = webcam.read()
   ret1,frame1 = webcam1.read()

   if(ret0):
        cv2.imshow('Webcam',frame)

   if(ret1):
        cv2.imshow('Webcam1',frame1)

   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   webcam.release()
   webcam1.release()
```

}

On running the code one camera starts running fine while the other raises an error below:

VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Could not obtain specifics of capture window.
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 1
/dev/video1 does not support memory mapping

How do I rectify this?

Comment: just a quick note. your indentation seems to be off. I am not sure your code will behave the way you intend, even after fixing the posted error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `webcam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`(the one that raises the error) to `webcam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`.

Also, check the camera drivers by `ls /dev/video*` to make sure all cameras plugged.